# Flutter Stripe web payment show CORS error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a Flutter app that uses Stripe Payments.

The payment is working on android and on ios app, but not on the web app.

I have deployed the needed index.js file to Firebase Cloud Functions.

This is the file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_...");


exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'eur',
            customer: customerId,
        })

        res.status(200).send({
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

On the web app, trying to perform the payment, an error is launched:

[image]

And also at the browser inspect console it is shown following messages:

[image]

What can I do to solve that issue?